# How can I fix small images on the Facebook website?

Tags: cyanogenmod, chrome-for-android, facebook, sony-xperia

Facebook images appear small, and don't take up whole width of the screen:

[image: news feed] [image: page of a singular image]
<sup>Screenshots (click images for larger variants)</sup>

This problem was reproduced on both Xperia T and Xperia SP (both running CM12, both have HD screen), and also both on Chrome and default CM web browser.

This problem didn't occur on Xperia Mini (HVGA screen), and I don't have any issues with the desktop version either.

Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try going to Settings > Apps > All > Chrome > Clear Data.

Or try Firefox if it works, or try installing the Facebook app. Or uninstalling Chrome and test the factory version if it works, or updating it to the latest stable version.

Oh! I see.. You are using Cyanogen? Try using other browsers, including Opera Mobile, Mozilla Firefox, and Dolphin Browser.

Comment: Changing the browser isn't an option here, I need the features of Chrome. That said, clearing data... actually fixed the issue.

Comment: Okay... Hope you like your new photo layouts!

Answer (score 2):

Which Chrome browser version you're using exactly?

So I just went around reading about the issue (of which I also experienced too), and realized it appears to be fixed already, at least for me.

To confirm again, I also quickly pulled my phone and tried viewing images on Facebook via Chrome, and they appeared nicely, not in small size.

Assuming the issue (which is likely a CSS issue) [was reported some months](http://www.reddit.com/r/oneplus/comments/2fo9s5/chrome_37_and_facebookcom_display_issue_very/) ago, I am sure they'll be at it and tried to fix it.

My images appear alright though. Perhaps update to the latest Chrome on phone and it might solve it for you. I didn't even noticed it's been fixed until reading this question and going to explicitly try it out.

As a proof, see image attached. This is how images show on my Chrome when I visit Facebook for mobile, the `m.facebook.com`

FWIW, my Chrome version is 42.0.23311.bla-bla-bla. I'm on Android 5.1.1, custom build, using CyanogenMod for Xperia Z2

[image: How Images Appear in Chrome]

Answer (score 0):

I've got two accounts the problem is only with one of them. The issue is with facebook trying out new stuff on select accounts. Nothing we can do from our phones